# Google Maps API - unexpected redirection

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, geolocation

I met unexpected redirection to localhost:xxxx/Home/null after executing this piece of code. What is the reason?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="userConsentSection">
Can we use your geolocation? <br />
    <input type="button" id="yes" value="Yes" />
    <input type="button" id="no" value="No" /><br /><br />
</div>

<div id="setCustomLocationSection">
    Enter your address manually.<br />
    <input type="text" id="customLocation" />
    <input type="button" id="setCustomLocationButton" value="Show" /><br /><br />
</div>

<div id="map" style="height: 450px; width: 720px" />
```

JS:

```
var map1 = null;
var location = null;

alert("alert4");

function initialize() {
    alert("alert5");
    $("#setCustomLocationSection").hide();

    var options =
        {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            zoom: 2
        }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        map: map,
        title: "Marker 0,0"
    });

    map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options)

    marker.setMap(map);
}

alert("alert3");

$("#yes").click(function () {
    $("#userConsentSection").hide();
    getPosition();
    reloadMap();
});

$("#no").click(function () {
    $("#userConsentSection").hide();
    showSetCustomLocationSection();
});

function showSetCustomLocationSection() {
    $("#setCustomLocationSection").show();
}

function getPosition() {

    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 2000
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, errorPosition, options);
}

function showPosition(position) {
    if (position) {
        location = position.coords;
    }
}

function errorPosition(position) {
    switch (position.code)
    {
        case 1:
            showSetCustomLocationSection();
            break;
        case 2:
            showSetCustomLocationSection();
            break;
        case 3:
            showSetCustomLocationSection();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function reloadMap()
{
    map1 = null;

    var options =
        {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude),
            zoom: 8
        }

    map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options)
}

alert("alert2");

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I've inserted alerts to show which pieces of code are executed and which not. It seems, something wrong with the last event method, but I've got no idea what, didn't notice any typo. Any idea?

Comment: Your default location is null. Perhaps you should set one incase the user does not allow their geolocation to be tracked. That's a start.

Comment: location is a reserved word in javascript... setting it can cause issues.

Comment: Thank you @geocodezip - that caused this problem.

Comment: Well it's not a reserved word, per se, but it is already declared within the `window` object. And the scope of your Javascript is inside `window`, therefore you just overwrote `window.location` when you set `location = null` because your Javascript interpreter (the browser) read that line as `window.location = null`.

Comment: You can fix the problem by declaring location as var to avoid conflicts with window.location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Location** is a <s>reserved word in javascript</s> property of the window object and therefore is redirecting the browser to /position.coords;

Thanks @peter for the clarification

Comment: It's not a reserved word but it's a property of the window object

Comment: Thanks for picking that up. I have corrected my answer.